# Can't open the page to enter my LEGO Advent Calendar code

Tags: star-wars, advent-calendar

I'm on a Mac and have been using the link provided in other posts to try to enter my Advent Calendar code.  But the page doesn't work for me.  This is the link I'm using:

http://starwars.lego.com/en-us/advent/Default.aspx

When the pop up finally opens it is just a blank page.

Comment: I'm on Mac and using Firefox, the link works for me. Does the rest of the lego site work? You might need to geta current version of flash player.

Comment: Hmmm.  I've tried with Safari and Firefox and get the same result.  The rest of the site seems to work.  I'm in Canada, does that make a difference?

Comment: I wouldn't think so. The box doesn't say US only. It took a while to load when I tried it sat morning but now it opens fine. Are your cookies turned on? It remembers the codes I've already entered. http://starwars.lego.com/en-us/default.aspx?domainredir=lego.com

Comment: The Star Wars pages (and many others on the LEGO site) are very heavily Flash based, are you able to view other Flash powered sites with any of your browsers? Do you see the flash animation on [Adobe's site](http://www.adobe.com/go/gffooter_adobe_flashplayer_uk)?

Answer (score 3):

> Thanks for getting in touch with us.
>
> We're sorry about the frustration you must be feeling. Unfortunately
>   there was a misprint on the packaging. The real website to enter the
>   codes is www.starwars.lego.com.
>
> When you get to the site in the middle of the page is a place for you
>   to enter in the codes. I hope this helped.
>
> Thanks again for getting in touch. We're always pleased to receive
>   feedback from LEGO fans! If you could take a moment to complete a four
>   question survey by going to the link below, it will help us make sure
>   we are providing the best customer service to you.
>
> http://www.econsumeraffairs.com/lsi/ensurvey.html?F1=032315854A
>
> Please let us know if you need anything else.
>
> Happy building!
>
> Arianne K LEGO Consumer Services

Comment: If this post is from an e-mail you received from LEGO please state so, I've placed the contents of the message in a quote so it doesn't appear to be attributed to you.